# Why did the skinned chickens fear the camera?

Tags: humanity-has-declined

It might be too much to ask for logic from this series, but maybe there is an answer somewhere.

In Episode 2 of Humanity has Declined, the narrator discovers that the board of directors of the factory producing weird items is a bunch of chickens that were butchered, plucked, and prepared for eating in Episode 1. They somehow came to life and gained intelligence and the ability to speak by making weird honking sounds. (The narrator can get overly literal subtitles of their language using a pair of universal translator glasses provided by her fairy companion.)

[image: butchered chicken]

The butchered chickens manage to trap the narrator in a cage and declare their intent to erase her memory with drugs and leave her somewhere far away to watch as they complete their insidious plan to destroy the ailing human society. However, the narrator's silent assistant enters and starts taking pictures of the chickens with his camera. For some reason, this terrifies them, and they run away. Several of them fall into the factory equipment and become food during the ensuing chase; the remaining group clusters against a seaside cliff and leaps into the sea rather than face the camera, while "Ave Maria" plays.

Pretty much everything about this episode is worthy of a big question mark, but I found it most puzzling that the chickens feared the camera so much that they leapt to their deaths rather than face it. (Yes, really, *that* was the part I found most puzzling.) Why were they so afraid of the camera?

Comment: I'm not sure but it might be because they didn't want their 'real forms' photographed - i need to rewatch the episode to be sure

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko That does make sense since it was pretty clear they were trying to hide their identities. I just watched it last night and I don't remember that being said directly, but the overwhelming weirdness was pretty distracting, so I may have missed a clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was correct in my earlier comment - The skinned chickens don't want to be revealed to humankind so they avoid being photographed.

This is revealed in the first dialogue with the chickens:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If they knew of their existance, humanity could easily overpower them because of the chickens' feeble bodies. Hence they try to avoid the assistant.

[image: enter preformatted text here]

Don't worry, the main character missed it too:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, between all the blurring of subtitles and complaining the narrator was doing during that scene, plus the dazed feeling I got from seeing something that weird on screen, it was hard to follow the nuance of the conversation. Thanks for your answer, +1.